# not executing the shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have one shell script.

```
#
. ./shprofile

if [ "$1" != "INSERT_ALL_ITEMS" -a "$1" != "INSERT_ONE_ITEM" ]
then
    echo "Usage: $0 [INSERT_ALL_ITEMS|INSERT_ONE_ITEM]"
exit
fi
   #
   echo "Start Date & Time is.." `date`
   case "$1" in
   INSERT_ALL_ITEMS)
    echo "Executing all Items"
    ;;
INSERT_ONE_ITEM)
    # 
    echo "Executing one Item"   
    ;;
*)
    echo "Invalid Options!!"
    ;;
esac
#
echo "Stop Date & Time is.." `date`
```

If I execute the above script with below command

```
./runItemsBatch.sh INSERT_ALL_ITEMS
```

Then  it is showing echo message, instead of executing the script

```
Usage: ./runItemsBatch.sh [INSERT_ALL_ITEMS|INSERT_ONE_ITEM]
```

What is the wrong in script? Why it is not executing the script, even though I give correct option. 
Need help.

Comment: Likely `shprofile` is manipulating the argument list (e.g. by executing `shift`). Since you're sourcing it, it is executing in the current environment and any changes it makes will be kept in your current environment. Try to comment that line out and test again.

Comment: I forgot tell that, If I execute like below ./runItemsBatch.sh INSERT_ONE_ITEM , then it is executing.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your script ran fine on my CentOS 7 virtual machine (*commenting the reference to the other file*), I think it may be that you didn't set up the interpreter properly.
The first line (`#`) should be a [shabang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) (`#!`) followed by the interpreter. e.g.: `#!/bin/sh`.

You could also try to remove the quotes for the arguments in your script because the interpreter could ...interpret them as literals.
I mean that you should try to replace the line

```
if [ "$1" != "INSERT_ALL_ITEMS" -a "$1" != "INSERT_ONE_ITEM" ]
```

with

```
if [ $1 != "INSERT_ALL_ITEMS" -a $1 != "INSERT_ONE_ITEM" ]
```

Try with either this two things. In my case however, the script worked with every combination of "*shabang / no shabang* and *quotes / no quotes*"

Hope I helped.

EDIT: Try also to delete the spaces between variables and operators in the if (Again, these are rules depending by the interpreter you are using, or defaulted to use)